# Thermal trip points seem poorly configured

Tags: linux, laptop, cooling, temperature

My laptop's shut down a couple of times recently during heavy compiles, and I think it might be due to overheating. Upon investigation, it turns out my thermal trip points are "passive" at 95°C and "critical" at 100°. From what I grasp, "passive" is just the default state of temperature control. So without an "active" trip point, will cooling be turning on at all?

If I'm right and this is poorly configured, how would I go about changing it? I think I understand that Linux doesn't let you configure the temperatures of the trip points, but can I set the modes? Or can I change both the mode and the temperature from within my BIOS? (I haven't checked yet, because I'm in the middle of another heavy compile.) Or is there something else I should be doing?

`acpi -tci` gives output like this:

```
$ acpi -tci
Thermal 0: ok, 64.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 100.0 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 1 switches to mode passive at temperature 95.0 degrees C
Cooling 0: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 1: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 2: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 3: Processor 0 of 3
```

I'm not sure what these cooling devices are. I'd expected fans, but maybe I don't have fans? I can manually set the processor state anywhere from 0 to 3 with e.g. `echo 3 | sudo tee /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device0/cur_state`. (This sets all four to the same state, "Processor 3 of 3".) Anecdotally, increasing the state does seem to improve cooling, but I don't notice any extra noise from my laptop. Earlier, I set the state to 1, and I later noticed it had gone back to 0 after the temperature had dropped (not under heavy load at the time, I forget the exact numbers but it probably happened somewhere between 80° and 60°). I haven't seen `acpi` report a temperature at 95° or higher; it recently made it to 94° before I turned on cooling. Right now it seems fairly stable at 84°, processors on state 3.

This is a Thinkpad Edge (E145) that I got in late 2013. Kernel 3.17.8-gentoo-r1, I configured it myself so it's possible I did something wrong.

**Update**: Twelve hours after the big compile finished, cooling hadn't turned off; I don't remember the temperature it had reached, maybe in the 70s. I looked in my BIOS, and couldn't find any options related to the thermal trip points. I've now seen it reach 95°; the first line changed to `Thermal 0: passive, 95.0 degrees C`, but nothing else changed. Then I turned on cooling myself.

Comment: If your device didn’t have any fans it would overheat immediately when it was turned on.

Comment: Hm, okay. That being the case, is there an obvious candidate for why I'm not seeing them in the `acpi` output?

Comment: Could be the tool at fault, could be the fact the fans are not configurable, hard to tell with so little information

Comment: Sure. I'm happy to try to gather more information, I'm just not sure what or how.

Answer (score 1):

Active means that the kernel is going to trigger and use any FAN to cool your computer.

Passive means that the kernel is going to throttle the CPU to cool your computer.

Critical means that the kernel is going to shut down.

I have posted a related question for an ARM system:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53094799/what-does-kernel-thermal-zone-mean-in-dts-file

There is also an interesting presentation (for ARM systems) that might give you a little bit of color on how the kernel thermal framework works:

https://elinux.org/images/2/2b/A_New_Simplified_Thermal_Framework_For_ARM_Platforms.pdf

The documentation of the kernel might help too:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/thermal/sysfs-api.txt

Last, this article is useful too:
https://lwn.net/Articles/268958/